# Nested theorem label

Tags: theorems, labels, counters

How can I define the theorem environments such that I get the following behaviour:

[image]

The code generating the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\thesection.\arabic{proposition}}
\newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.\arabic{question}}
\newcommand{\questionautorefname}{Q.}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{reflection}{Reflection}
\renewcommand{\thereflection}{}
\newcommand{\reflectionautorefname}{Reflection}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proposition}
        My proposition
        \begin{reflection}
            My reflection should be numbered 0.1.1. or 1
        \end{reflection}
        \begin{reflection}
            My reflection should be numbered 0.1.2. or 2
        \end{reflection}
    \end{proposition}
    \begin{question}
        My question
        \begin{reflection}
            My reflection should be numbered 0.1.1. or 1
        \end{reflection}
        \begin{reflection}
            My reflection should be numbered 0.1.2. or 2
        \end{reflection}
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I interpret your objective as follows: The `reflection` counter should be reset if either a new `proposition` environment or a new `question` counter is encountered. Is this interpretation correct? Please advise.

Comment: Incidentally, with your setup, the `proposition` and `question` counters will *not* be reset when a `\section` directive is encountered. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- To have the `reflection` environments be numbered consecutively -- `1`, `2`, etc -- *and* be reset each time either a new `proposition` or `question` environment comes along, you should delete the instruction `\renewcommand{\thereflection}{}` and replace it with

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{reflection}{proposition}
  \@addtoreset{reflection}{question}
  \makeatother
  ```

  or, equivalently and also more succinctly, as pointed out by @egreg in a comment,

  ```
  \counterwithin*{reflection}{proposition}
  \counterwithin*{reflection}{question}
  ```

  (This works because `\counterwithin*{reflection}{proposition}` is equivalent to `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{reflection}{proposition} \makeatother`.)
- To get the number of the `reflection` environment to be prefixed with either the `proposition` or the `question` number (whichever occurred most recently), while still executing a reset whenever a `proposition` or `question` environment is encountered, you should still delete the instruction `\renewcommand{\thereflection}{}`, but now you should replace it with

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\counterwithin{reflection}{proposition}}
  \AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\counterwithin{reflection}{question}}
  ```
- By the way, if you want the `proposition` and `question` counters to be reset each time the `section` counter is incremented via a `\section` directive, you should change

  ```
  \renewcommand{\theproposition}{\thesection.\arabic{proposition}}
  ```

  and

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.\arabic{question}}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \counterwithin{proposition}{section}
  ```

  and

  ```
  \counterwithin{question}{section}
  ```

  respectively. Alternatively, drop the two `\renewcommand` statements and change the statements

  ```
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
  ```

  and

  ```
  \newtheorem{question}{Question}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
  ```

  and

  ```
  \newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
  ```

  respectively.

Incidentally, the second and third instances of `\theoremstyle{definition}` in your code are redundant and could (should?!) be omitted.

Comment: Why `\@addtoreset`? Why not `\counterwithin*`?

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've updated my answer to mention the `\counterwithin*` method and to note that `\counterwithin*{reflection}{proposition}` is equivalent to (but also more succinct than) `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{reflection}{proposition} \makeatother`.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily number `reflection` according to either `proposition` or `question`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{Proposition}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\newcommand{\questionautorefname}{Q.}

\newtheorem{reflection}{Reflection}
\newcommand{\reflectionautorefname}{Reflection}

\counterwithin*{reflection}{proposition}
\counterwithin*{reflection}{question}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{proposition}
My proposition
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered 1
\end{reflection}
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered 2
\end{reflection}
\end{proposition}

\begin{question}
My question
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered or 1
\end{reflection}
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered or 2
\end{reflection}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit more complicated if you want to add the `proposition` or `question` number.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{propositioninner}{Proposition}[section]
\newcommand{\propositioninnerautorefname}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{proposition}
  {%
   \renewcommand{\PropositionOrQuestion}{\thepropositioninner}%
   \propositioninner
  }
  {\endpropositioninner}

\newtheorem{questioninner}{Question}[section]
\newcommand{\questioninnerautorefname}{Q.}
\newenvironment{question}
 {%
  \renewcommand{\PropositionOrQuestion}{\thequestioninner}%
  \questioninner
 }
 {\endquestioninner}

\newcommand{\PropositionOrQuestion}{}
\newtheorem{reflection}{Reflection}
\newcommand{\reflectionautorefname}{Reflection}

\counterwithin*{reflection}{propositioninner}
\counterwithin*{reflection}{questioninner}
\renewcommand{\thereflection}{\PropositionOrQuestion.\arabic{reflection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{proposition}
My proposition
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered 1.1.1
\end{reflection}
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered 1.1.2
\end{reflection}
\end{proposition}

\begin{question}
My question
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered or 1.1.1
\end{reflection}
\begin{reflection}
My reflection should be numbered or 1.1.2
\end{reflection}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found your answer as valuable as the accepted answer. I decided to accept Mico's answer since he has less reputation.